# Need a hint: Prove / Disprove: There is an entire function $f(z)$ so that for every $z \in \mathbb C$, $z=x+iy$, $|f(z)|=e^{-x^2-y^2}$

Tags: complex-analysis

Need a hint: Prove / Disprove: There is an entire function $f(z)$ so that for every $z \in \mathbb  C$, $z=x+iy$, $|f(z)|=e^{-x^2-y^2}$.

Any hint or direction on how to think on this type of questions will be of great assistance.

Thank you!

**edit:**
Solution I thought of, not sure if correct.

Assume such entire $f$ exists, so that $|f(z)|=e^{-x^2-y^2}=e^{-(x^2+y^2)}$. Let $C_R$ be a circle centered at $z=0$ and with radius $R$. Assume WLG $R>1$. So $f$ is holomorphic there, and non-constant. So by the maximum principle we get that $max |f(z)|$ is obtained when $|z|=R$, so $\sqrt {x^2+y^2}=R$. So $max |f(z)|=e^{-R^2}$, but we know that $z=1 \in C_R$ and it is clear that $e^{-R^2} \lt e^{-1}$, so $e^{-R^2}$ is not the maximum. Contradiction. So such $f$ does not exist.

Comment: What are x and y? The real and imaginary part of z?

Comment: I guess so, the original question doesn't include that either.

Comment: .....Liouville?

Comment: So can I just say $|f(z)| \leq 1$ so it is constant, but for $z=1$ and $z=2$, $|f(1)| \neq |f(2)|$, contradiction for $f$ being constant?

Answer (score 1):

It can be seen that $f(z) \neq 0$ for all $z$, hence an analytic branch of $\log f$ can be defined, with real part $$ \log |f(z)|=-x^2-y^2 .$$

Since the real part of an analytic function has to be harmonic we see that such $f$ doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1):

Solution I thought of, not sure if correct.

Assume such entire $f$ exists, so that $|f(z)|=e^{-x^2-y^2}=e^{-(x^2+y^2)}$. Let $C_R$ be a circle centered at $z=0$ and with radius $R$. Assume WLG $R>1$. So $f$ is holomorphic there, and non-constant. So by the maximum principle we get that $max |f(z)|$ is obtained when $|z|=R$, so $\sqrt {x^2+y^2}=R$. So $max |f(z)|=e^{-R^2}$, but we know that $z=1 \in C_R$ and it is clear that $e^{-R^2} \lt e^{-1}$, so $e^{-R^2}$ is not the maximum. Contradiction. So such $f$ does not exist.

Comment: so by "circle" you mean "closed disc" ? also why did you use $1$ where you could have just used $0$ (which is where $|f|$ is maximal by hypothesis)

Comment: Yes. And I dunno, doesn't really matter.

Comment: yeah it's fine, it just sounds strange in the grand scheme of things.

Answer (score 1):

The hypothesis says that $f$ has a removable singularity at infinity, and so is entire on the sphere. Thus it is constant—0 in fact—by Liouville, contradicting the hypothesis.